# Objective-C pointers?

Tags: objective-c, oop, pointers

I am new to coding and trying to get up to speed with Objective-C.
Came across some code I did not understand. I was hoping someone could
clarify it for me. In the case below, I am not sure how *foo2 is working and why it is not being released?

```
ClassOne *pointer = [[ClassOne alloc]init];

ClassTwo *foo = [[ClassTwo alloc]init], *foo2; 

 foo2 = [foo add: pointer];
 [foo release]; 
 foo = foo2

[pointer release];

[foo release];
```

Comment: What are the class names of those classes?

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not sure if this came about in the process of anonymizing the code or what, but that code is pretty confusing considering it's only seven lines.

Answer (score 22):

With Objective-C Cocoa, we're working with semi-automatic reference-counting memory management.  When allocating memory for an object, retaining an object, or calling a `copy` method on an object, the retain count (reference count) increments by 1.  When calling `release` on an object, it decrements the retain count by one.  When calling `autorelease` on an object, `release` will be called on the object at some point in the future (during the main run loop, when none of your own code is executing, so it won't pull the reference out from under you as you're trying to use it).  When the retain count reaches 0, the object can be deallocated.

In general, if you're calling `retain` on an object, you're signalling your interest in it, and you are responsible for making a `release` or `autorelease` call at some point when you're no longer interested in the object.  Likewise, if you call `alloc` or a `copy` method on an object, you have signalled your interest in the object and must match it with a `release` or `autorelease` somewhere down the line.

This link pretty much covers the guidelines Apple uses (and you should use) for memory management:  [Simple rules for memory management in Cocoa](http://www.stepwise.com/Articles/Technical/2001-03-11.01.html)

Let's go through the code line by line:

> ```
> ClassOne *pointer = [[ClassOne alloc]init];
> ```

`pointer` points to a newly allocated ClassOne object, with a retain count of 1, since we called alloc on it.  We have a responsibility to call `release` or `autorelease` on `pointer` at some point in the future.

> ```
> ClassTwo *foo = [[ClassTwo alloc]init], *foo2;
> ```

`foo` points to a newly allocated ClassTwo object, with a retain count of 1, since we called alloc on it.  We have a responsibility to call `release` or `autorelease` on `foo` at some point in the future.

`foo2` doesn't point to anything in particular right now.  It's not safe to use.

> ```
> foo2 = [foo add: pointer];
> ```

`pointer` has been added to `foo` (whatever that means; we don't know the implementation).  `foo` might have called `retain` on `pointer` to signal its interest in it, and added it as a field, or it might have added `pointer` to a collection (in which case it's the collection's responsibility to call `retain` on it when an object is added, and `release` when an object is removed).  In any case, it doesn't affect our code block, so we don't care what's going on under the hood

The reference returned by this method might be `pointer` itself, or it might be an autoreleased copy of `pointer`; we don't have access to the API or the implementation to tell us which.

In either case, it is not our responsibility to call `release` on this object.  If the method had `copy` in the name, or if we had called `retain` on the returned reference (like `foo2 = [[foo add:pointer] retain];`), then the retain count would have been incremented by 1, and it would have been our responsibility to call `release` or `autorelease` on it.

> ```
> [foo release];
> ```

The object referenced by `foo` has been released, meaning its retain count has been decremented by 1.  For this example, this pairs with the `alloc` call we made in line 2, so the retain count will drop to 0, making `foo` eligible to be freed.

In general, though, we don't care if the object has been deallocated or not; we just need to make sure we pair up any `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain` calls with the same number of `release` or `autorelease` calls.  If we register an interest in an object at any time, it's our responsibility to release our interest, otherwise we'll have memory leaks.

> ```
>  foo = foo2;
> ```

`foo` now points to the same object referenced by `foo2`.  Remember, we haven't called an `alloc` or `copy` method when we got `foo2`, nor did we register an interest in it by calling `retain`.  Since we don't have a responsibility to call `release` on `foo2`, we don't have a responsibility to call `release` on `foo`.

> ```
> [pointer release];
> ```

`pointer`'s retain count has been decremented by 1.  This may have brought its retain count to 0 or not, it depends on what `foo` did with it when we added it.  Still, we don't care; we have finished our responsibility to `pointer` by calling `release` on it to match with the `alloc` call we made at the beginning.  Although `pointer` might still be around after this call, we can't make that assumption, and trying to do anything with the object previously referenced by pointer would be a mistake (though we could change `pointer` to point at something else freely).

> ```
> [foo release];
> ```

If the author of this code has been following Apple's memory management conventions, then this is unnecessary.  We don't have a responsibility to call `release` on `foo` or `foo2` (they point to the same object, remember).  This won't cause the code to break; calling anything on a `nil` reference is essentially a no-op.  However, it may cause confusion for anyone reviewing the code.

Now, the author of this code may have broken the memory management conventions.  He might have made that `add` call return a copy of `pointer` without calling `autorelease` on it, in which case it makes the caller responsible for calling `release` on it.  This is very bad form, and if you should run into code which breaks the memory management convention, document where you use it and how it breaks the convention to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: The [foo release] at the end probably *will* cause a crash if we're following the memory-management guidelines. It's set to the result of [foo add:pointer], which we don't know is nil. If it's anything other than nil, program go boom.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClassOne *pointer = [[ClassOne alloc]init];
```

The variable `pointer` is a pointer to an object of class ClassOne. It it assigned the value of a newly created object.

```
ClassTwo *foo = [[ClassTwo alloc]init], *foo2;
```

`*foo` and `*foo2` are objects of class `ClassTwo`. Only `foo` is assigned a newly created object. `foo2` may point to anything, so it is unsafe to use it before assigning it a value.

```
 foo2 = [foo add: pointer];
```

`foo2` is assigned a value: I assume that the `add:` message of class `ClassTwo` creates an object (the signature of the method should be `-(ClassTwo*)add:(ClassOne*);`)

```
 [foo release];
```

The object pointed to by `foo` is no longer needed.

```
 foo = foo2;
```

The variable `foo` is assigned the value of `foo2`: both point to the same object.

```
[pointer release];
```

The object pointed to by `pointer` is no longer needed.

```
[foo release];
```

The object pointed to by `foo` (and also by `foo2`) is no longer needed.

Comment: Actually, the signature of the method should be - (ClassTwo*) add:(ClassOne*); -- in his/her example, the receiver is an instance of ClassTwo, not the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't released it. You're releasing references here, not freeing pointers. It's not quite the same thing. When you do [foo release] the second time, you're releasing the foo reference that you created when you assigned foo2 to foo.

To release the foo2 reference, you need to actually call release on that reference, not a copy of the reference.

Answer (score 1):

From your simple example it is really hard to say what is going on.  Typically [class add:] type methods return void, so they should raise a compiler warning that 'void value is not ignored as it should be.'

So without more info, it is a bit hard to figure things out.

A few things to keep in mind:

- you can send commands to 'nil' in objc.  So, if [foo add:pointer] returns nil, then you can call 'release' on it all day with no affect.
- retainCount is your friend.  You can call it on any NSObject to see how many objects are holding onto it.  This may also help you track down the issue.
- Finally, is Garbage Collection on?

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on what `[foo add:pointer];` does. It looks like it gives back a **copy** of `foo` and retaining it. This is clearly bad design because it should be obvious from the method if the returned object is a copy / reference. Methods with named `add:` shouldn't give back a copy.

Step by step:

```
// this somehow creates a retained copy of foo.
foo2 = [foo add:pointer];

 // foo is released and gets destroyed.
[foo release];

// makes foo point to the same object as foo2
// (`foo` has no connection to the former object anymore)
foo = foo2;

// foo (and foo2 as they point to the same object) are released
[foo release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, Thank you all for the great responses!

I guess what I am really meant is a reference to an object and not a pointer. Nonetheless I guessing the appended `, *foo2` resides in the same memory as foo. Also foo2 is released form memory at the same time as foo. I still have a lot more to lean but one day at a time!

Answer (score 0):

What you really try to focus on is how pointers work. I think you haven't yet understood the difference between pointers and objects.

[Here's the link to pointers on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointers).